# Meaning of symbol $\looparrowright$ in math

Tags: notation

Is there a conventional meaning for the symbol $\looparrowright$ when used in math.

I came across this symbol in [here](http://www.commsp.ee.ic.ac.uk/~mandic/ASP_Slides/ASP_Lecture_1_Slides_2018.pdf) (see slide 2 for e.g.).

Comment: It seems that it is being used as an "em dash". For more information, see <https://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html>. I want to add that it is certainly not standard, and personally is somewhat distracting.

Comment: @AlbertoTakase I'm not sure, it still confuses me.

Answer (score 1):

I personally sometimes use it as another way for epimorphism/surjection when additional distinction matters: just like $\hookrightarrow$ is reserved for an inclusion map as many people do while $\rightarrowtail$ is for general injection, I reserve $\looparrowright$ for a map from $X$ to its decomposition (dual of inclusion map), while $\twoheadrightarrow$ is for general surjection.